# Customize React Native drawer navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to create drawer navigation like that

[image]

I able to add icons but don't know how to design right side like in the image

that's my drawer navigator

```
 <Drawer.Navigator
          drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawer {...props} />}
          drawerStyle={{
            width: '80%',
          }}>
          <Drawer.Screen name={strings.NAV_HOME} component={StackComp} />
          <Drawer.Screen name={strings.NAV_MY_PROFILE} component={Proifle} />
          <Drawer.Screen name={strings.NAV_SETTING} component={Setting} />
          <Drawer.Screen
            name={strings.NAV_MANAGE_BOOKING}
            component={Booking}
          />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
```

and that's my customize code

```
 <DrawerContentScrollView
        style={{backgroundColor: colors.themeColor, flex: 1}}
        {...props}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              paddingTop: moderateScaleVertical(24),
            }}>
            <Image
              source={imagePath.logo}
              style={{marginLeft: moderateScale(16)}}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate(strings.NAV_HOME)}
              style={styles.drawCont}>
              <Image source={imagePath.homeIcon} />
              <Text style={styles.text}>{strings.HOME}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
```

Can someone tell me how can I design it like in the image?

Comment: Any solution yet??

Answer (score 0):

To create a `drawer` component you can check the official [documentation here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/)

You will then have to make use of icons such as `MaterialCommunityIcons`. First on your drawer navigator import `MaterialCommunityIcons` like this

`import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";`
Then add an `options` props on screen navigation as shown

```
<Drawer.Screen name={strings.NAV_HOME} component={StackComp}  options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

nice to meet you.
pls check my code....

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const Main = () => {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Home"
            tabBarOptions={{
                activeTintColor: '#fda039', 
                activeBackgroundColor: 'transparent', 
                labelPosition: 'bottom-icon', 
                tabStyle: styles.tabStyle,
                style: styles.tabBarStyle,
            }}>
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home}
            options={{
                tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="home" color={color}/>,
                tabBarLabel: ({ focused, color}) => focused?<Text style={{color: color, marginTop: 5, fontSize: 14}}>Hogar</Text>: null,
              }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen name="QRscan" component={ProfileScreen}
            options={{
                tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="qr-code-scanner" color={color}/>,
                tabBarLabel: ({ focused, color}) => focused?<Text style={{color: color, marginTop: 5, fontSize: 14}}>QR Scan</Text>: null,
              }}
            />
         <Tab.Screen name="Help" component={Help}
            options={{
                tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="help" color={color}/>,
                tabBarLabel: ({ focused, color}) => focused?<Text style={{color: color, marginTop: 5, fontSize: 16}}>Ayuda</Text>: null,
              }}
            />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
```

It's my project code running now using React Native navigator.
It's using react bottom navigation.

You can rewrite the code like mine.

Thank you.